# SAS Nested If Statements Producing Incorrect Result

Tags: if-statement, sas

ID no. 6 returns 'Underweight' when it should return 'Overweight'.
The lines of code in question, lines 30-53, contain nested if statements and produce a single undesirable result. The purpose of these lines is to partition the sample into classifications of weight class: Underweight, Average or Overweight.

```
TITLE 'A SHORT SAS PROGRAM';
OPTIONS LS=72;
* Create data file with height and weight data;

DATA HTWT;
    INPUT ID GENDER $ HEIGHT WEIGHT;
    DATALINES;
1 M 68.5 155.0
2 F 61.2 99.00
3 F 63.0 115.0
4 M 70.0 205.0
5 M 68.6 170.0
6 F 65.1 125.0
7 M 72.4 220.0
;
    * Create a new categorical variable for height;

DATA HTWT;
    SET work.HTWT;

    IF HEIGHT < 68 THEN
        STATURE='Short';

    IF HEIGHT >=68 THEN
        STATURE='Tall';
RUN;

* Create a new categorical variable for weight;

DATA HTWT;
    SET work.HTWT;

    IF GENDER='M' THEN
        IF WEIGHT > 170 THEN
            WEIGHT_CLASS='Overweight';

        IF 170 >=WEIGHT >=150 THEN
            WEIGHT_CLASS='Average';

        IF WEIGHT < 140 THEN
            WEIGHT_CLASS='Underweight';

        ELSE IF GENDER='F' THEN
            IF WEIGHT > 120 THEN
                WEIGHT_CLASS='Overweight';

            IF 120 >=WEIGHT >=100 THEN
                WEIGHT_CLASS='Average';

            IF WEIGHT < 100 THEN
                WEIGHT_CLASS='Underweight';
        RUN;

        * Changing units of height from inches to centimeters;

        DATA HTWT;
            SET work.HTWT;
            HEIGHT=2.54 * HEIGHT;
        RUN;

        * Creates HEALTH_INDEX;

        DATA HTWT;
            SET work.HTWT;
            HEALTH_INDEX=WEIGHT/HEIGHT;
        RUN;

        * Print the data file HTWT;

        PROC PRINT DATA=HTWT;
            TITLE 'HEIGHT AND WEIGHT DATA';
        RUN;

        * Sorts the data by gender. Some procedures require sorted data;

        PROC SORT DATA=HTWT OUT=sorted;
            BY GENDER;
        RUN;

        * Print the sorted data file;

        PROC PRINT DATA=sorted;
            TITLE 'GENDER SORTED HTWT DATA';
        RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your nested if statement into:

```
 IF  GENDER='M' THEN do;
     IF WEIGHT > 170 THEN
        WEIGHT_CLASS='Overweight';

    else if 150 <= Weight <= 170 THEN
        WEIGHT_CLASS='Average';

    else
        WEIGHT_CLASS='Underweight';
    end;

 else do;
    IF WEIGHT > 120 THEN
        WEIGHT_CLASS='Overweight';

    else iF 100 <= Weight =< 120 THEN
        WEIGHT_CLASS='Average';

    else
        WEIGHT_CLASS='Underweight';
 end;
```

See if it works?

Comment: This will most likely generated a 'no matching end statement for do statement', you've omitted the first `end` statement. Otherwise, the logic is sound. I would also keep the `else if gender = 'F'` which at least gives missing values if an errant gender value appears.

Comment: OK guys, good news, we've got it working!
Added IF  GENDER='M' THEN DO; and ELSE IF GENDER='F' THEN DO;

Comment: Added IF  GENDER='M' THEN DO; and ELSE IF GENDER='F' THEN DO; with the END; bit. Also an ELSE IF bit for all following WEIGHT x number comparisons. I'm a little confused about how the ELSE IF commands freely overlap but it's working so I'll work it out later.

Comment: i would recommend you to  implement `else if` in your inner nested if clauses i.e. when bounding weight to category

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't accept my answer as the correct one, 'cause I'm late and previos answers are clear and useful.
But I'm here to give you a simple advice, when you have to concatenate a lot of nested if statement, please use select when statement (coming from sql language) to give a stratum to all possible variable's value.

```
data want;
set have;
if gender='M' then do;
select (weight);
   when (>x) weight_class='';
   when (<y) weight_class='';
   otherwise weight_class=''
end;
end;
else if gender='F' then do;
select (weight);
   when (>x) weight_class='';
   when (<y) weight_class='';
   otherwise weight_class=''
end;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consecutive IF statements are processed in order.  So since the last one is testing if WEIGHT is < 100 then of course number 6 is being listed as underweight.
If you want to control execution order add some ELSE and/or DO/END blocks. Your basic structure probably should look like this.

```
if A then do;
  if B then xxx ;
  else if C then xxx ;
  else if D then xxxx ;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my description: in the data table I put in the code, the 6th row details the 6th person in the data table, this person has a weight value of 125, so it should say 'overweight'. I'll give the DO blocks a try though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If statements are useful but sometimes it is safer to create a format and use put statements to do the assignments. This is particularly true if you would have to do a lot of IFs since in my case at least, the more typing I do, the greater is my chance of screwing up.

The code with the put statements is a lot easier to check and maintain.